# Call to undefined method after creating new model (Laravel 4.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I just set up a new model and I am trying to call a custom written static method that I've written from inside a new controller to match the model:

```
<?php

class NewModelWebController extends AjaxController {

    public function newModelView() {
        $loggedUser = Auth::user();
        $data['user'] = $loggedUser;
        $data['allDetails'] = NewModel::getFullWithDetails($loggedUser->user_id);

        return View::make('webApp::new-model.view', $data);
    }

}
```

Here is the method definition inside the model class (there are no spaces before the php declaration):

```
<?php

class NewModel extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'new_models';
   protected $primaryKey = 'new_model_id';

   public static function getFullWithDetails($userId) { 
       return 1; // doesn't matter what I return -- the problem still happens
   }

}
```

The error that is returned is the following:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getFullWithDetails()`

When I make calls such as `NewModel::find(1);` it works with no issues, but once I try to make calls on the method I wrote, it does not work.

I tried all of the following commands with no success:

- `composer update`
- `composer dump-autoload`
- `composer clear-cache`
- `chown -R www-data:www-data ./theProjectFile`

Thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: How do you call your function inside your model?

Comment: What does the `use` statement look like for `NewModel` where you're attempting to call the static method?

Comment: I've updated the question, but the call to the method happens inside of a controller class. Like I said before, `NewModel::find(1)` will work when called in that controller, but my custom method will not work. As for the `use` statement, there is no such statement inside the controller class where it is called. Only thing I can think of is if further up the inheritance / include chain hierarchy there is some kind of `use` statement that I can't see from the controller I'm calling from. But I haven't seen any `use` or `include` statements inside other similar controllers, either. @Phil

Comment: I don't know Laravel but at a guess I'd say it's registering `Builder` classes as model symbols. I'd try using the full class name, eg `\Namespace\Path\To\NewModel::getFullWithDetails()`. Chances are you're going to run into other problems after that though.

Comment: @phil I definitely agree with that statement, but I'm not sure how applicable it is this case. Composer does have the class mapped in the autoload files, so the issue doesn't appear to be there. It's strange, though, because I can make calls to other Models just fine. It's just this new model that is giving me issues, so clearly it's not being included somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to recreate the model from scratch. There must have been a problem with file encoding or filetype when I initially created it because originally I just duplicated another model class and then changed the values inside. Creating a brand new file and then pasting the PHP content back in fixed the issue! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just as added info, Laravel 5 appears to have support in the Artisan CLI for creating models on the command line. Unfortunately for us still stuck on 4 we have to do it manually!

Answer (score 0):

Try using scopes instead of actual static methods.

```
class NewModel extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeGetFullWithDetails($userId)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Calling is the same. `NewModel::getFullWithDetails(1);`

Comment: I also tried this, and it did not work. Besides, I should be able to have and call both static and non static functions.. But I can't do either, as long as they are the ones that I've written.

Comment: @Max your calling might be referencing another class. Are you sure there are no aliases for or any other class named *NewModel*? The problem is not in your model.

Comment: I did a search for that new model name in Github and nothing turned up, so there doesn't appear to be any name conflicts. I also rolled back migrations, cleared cache, and re-ran just to make sure it wasn't a DB problem. The same error still comes up :(

Comment: What exactly does your model extend? Make sure in your `config/app.php`, under `alias` array, `Eloquent` points to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. Also can you post your full `NewModel.php` file?

Comment: app.php is good and points to Eloquent correctly. Like I said before I can reference other models no problem throughout the app; it's just the new one that's giving me grief. I've updated the question to show exactly what's in the controller and the model. Thank you :)